# Implementing Integer Division in Haskell by Hand

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, division

For a homework assignment in Haskell I want to implement binary search, but I'm not allowed to use any predefined functions.

What I'm struggling with is implementing a way of efficiently finding the middle element of a list, so basically I want to calculate

```
(length x) `div` 2
```

for some given list x.

The only implementation I could think of is

```
halfOf :: Int -> Int
halfOf 0 = 0
halfOf 1 = 0
halfOf x = 1 + halfOf (x - 2)
```

but this is terribly slow. Is there some faster way I could implement this without using any predefined functions?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Binary searching a list doesn't really make sense, it's not an array. Maybe there is some trick to efficiently take an average without calling a predefined function, but in the bigger picture I don't think that will help.

Comment: As @nicomp mentioned, in Haskell, lists are not arrays, but singly linked lists. Therefore you aren't actually getting a performance advantage with a binary search - the best you can do is an O(n) iterative search.

Comment: `div` is predefined but `+` and `-` aren't? ...why?

Comment: @nicomp I agree, though there is one way it _could_ make sense: if the list elements are expensive to compute and not needed elsewhere. Then laziness allows you to evaluate only _O_ (log _n_) if using binary search, whereas brute-force would require _O_ (_n_) to be evaluated.

Comment: You may also want to ask for clarification from your teacher. It's absurd not to allow the basic mathematical function of division in an exercise about list searching. My guess is they meant to say "no built-in *list* functions are allowed".

Comment: I wasn't aware of the fact that lists aren't arrays, I'll look into the differences. Thank you for your responses everybody!

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Now that you mention it that would make sense, I'll ask him.

Comment: @DanielWagner It could very well be that I'm overthinking what is meant by no predefined functions and like Silvio mentioned it might just apply to functions on lists, I'll look into that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were going to try to do this without using `length` or `div`, here's what I would do. Step 1 is to "efficiently" cut the length in half; in step two we'll make sure we also have the right elements.

```
halfAsLong :: [a] -> [a]
halfAsLong (x:y:rest) = x:halfAsLong rest
halfAsLong short = short
```

Once we have that, we can use it to split a list at the halfway point by iterating along the list and its half-as-long counterpart at once<sup>1</sup>.

```
splitLength :: [a] -> [b] -> ([b], [b])
splitLength (a:as) (b:bs) = let (pre, post) = splitLength as bs in (b:pre, post)
splitLength _ bs = ([], bs)
```

We can now combine the two.

```
halfsies :: [a] -> ([a], [a])
halfsies as = splitLength (halfAsLong as) as
```

Try it out:

```
> mapM_ (print . halfsies) ["", "a", "ab", "abc", "abcd", "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"]
("","")
("a","")
("a","b")
("ab","c")
("ab","cd")
("abcdefghijklm","nopqrstuvwxyz")
```

<sup>1</sup> Actually, if I were doing this, and not trying to teach a beginner, I'd at least use a lazy pattern:

```
... let ~(pre, post) = splitLength ... in ...
```

and probably also experiment with using a difference list to see if it was faster:

```
splitLength = go id where
    go pre (a:as) (b:bs) = go (pre . (b:)) as bs
    go pre _ bs = (pre [], bs)
```

If `id` and `(.)` count as "predefined functions", I'd define copies myself or just use the lambda they represent inline.

Comment: Unluckily `(:)` is pre-defined too.  Time to brush up on Church encoding.

Comment: @amalloy Yeah... I considered calling that out. `data List a = Nil | Cons a (List a)`...?

Comment: I think this is what I was looking for, I'll work through what you wrote and try to understand it. As some of the commentors said maybe I just misunderstood the extend of operators which aren't allowed. Thank you very much for taking to time to respond.

Comment: @amalloy well, `(:)` is not a library function but a library _constructor_. Constructors can't perform arbitrary computation, so even if the rules were so strict to exclude numerical operations this should definitely be ok. (Unless cheating with `-XPatternSynonyms`...)

Comment: The pattern is lazy without `~`, thanks to what I see as a mistake in the design of Haskell.

Comment: You can skip `halfAsLong` and `splitLength` in favor of [a single tortoise and hare algorithm](https://gist.github.com/treeowl/6098e08debe2d5580e4982be13865fb8).

Comment: @dfeuer Sure, why not. It's essentially an inlining of `halfAsLong` into `splitLength`.